# what physical meaning of spin gap, why we can relate spin gap with spin correlation function by fitting $G_{sp}(\tau, 0)$?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

In non-interacting limit, single particle gap is the energy between fermi-level and occupied/unoccupied energy band. And we can get this gap by the formulation: $G_k(\tau,0) = <c_k^+(\tau)c_k(0)> \sim exp(-\sum_{k}^{unocc}(E_k-E_f)\tau)$
. So, we can get lowest value of $E_k - E_f$ which is smallest excited energy of adding one electron with wavevector $k$ into the system. My question is:

1. While, in the interacting system, $c_k^+$ is not a well defined quasi-particle, and the DOS of electron with wavevector $k$ is no longer $
   \delta$ function and we can't read $(E_k-E_f)$ from energy band at $k$ point more. So, is there exist any relation between single particle gap with correlated electron energy band with $\rho_k (\omega) = \frac1\pi Im(G_k^r(\omega)) $?
2. Does spin gap can obtained by fitting $G_{sp}(\tau,0)=<s_k^z(\tau)s_{-k}^z(0)>\sim exp(-\sum_{k}(E_k(spin)-E_f(spin))\tau)$? And what the physical meaning of E_k(spin)-E_f(spin)?

Comment: Look into Greens function techniques in condensed matter, especially Lehnman representation of retarded green's function whose poles provide information of quasiparticle excitations above fermi-level (whose imaginary part gives the interacting spectral function).

Comment: Many books introduce Lehnman representation of single particle green function and I am clear about single particle gap and its relation to dynamic green function. However, I can't understand the what  spin gap means and the relation between spin gap and  dynamic spin correlation.

Comment: Mahan in "Many-Particle Physics" (chapter 4) interprets the poles of $\langle s_{k}^{z}(\tau) s_{-k}^{z}(0) \rangle$ as the energies of spin excitations (magnon waves). Generally  poles of appropriate higher order (in terms of basic creation and annhilation operators) correlation functions are interpreted as energies of collective excitations (plasmon, magnon) for many particle systems or energies of bound states in case of few particle systems (excitons).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I should read the related chapter.